# How to prevent to delete the build directory when cleaning a build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ramdisk

I am now using Android Studio 3.1.3 version.
When clicked `Build/Clean` menu, it delete the build directory.(for example: `app/build` directory)

By the way, I want to retain the `build` directory only.
On the other hand, I want to delete the sub-directories and files in build directory.

How to modify the "`clean`" feature in gradle build?

(Because I am using "`soft link`" of `build` directory and the real `build` directory is located in `RAMDISK`.)

Comment: So you simply want 'build' to be preserved? If so, would re-creation be fine (it should not mess with static links)

Comment: @shkschneider Can I create the soft link of the specific directory when cleaning a build?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the `$buildDir` on each project rather than using a soft link? See [Project.setBuildDir(File)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#setBuildDir-java.io.File-)

Eg

```
ext {
    ramDiskRoot = 'z:/foo' 
} 
allprojects {
    buildDir = "$ramDiskRoot/$name/build"
}
```

If you wanted to keep this logic outside of your buildscript you could use an [init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html)

Comment: I used the init script before. But a lot of errors were found such as "cannot create directory " when using lambda method. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Possibly using File.mkdir() instead of File.mkdirs() but hard to help without seeing it. Possibly best to open a new question for that